# Expand transparent background on hover effect of an icon

Tags: html, css, hover

I need some help to simply/correct my code.
I have an icon and I want its transparent background to go over the entire image it is hovering on. I think my approach is wrong with what I am doing now. Some suggestions?

My understanding of hover is still at the beginning and I am trying to build stuff in order to fully grasp it.

Here is the code:

```css
body {
  background-color: hsl(217, 54%, 11%);
}
.container {
  width: 19rem;
  height: 32rem;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Outfit", sans-serif;
  background-color: hsl(216, 50%, 16%);
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 8.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.7rem;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black;
}

/* I need help here*/

.equilibrium {
  width: 19rem;
  border-radius: 0.7rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-hover:hover .view {
  display: block;
  background-color: hsl(178, 100%, 50%, 0.5);
}

.view {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 42%;
  right: 47.5%;
}

.equilibrium .container h4:hover {
  color: cyan;
}
.container h4 {
  color: white;
}
.container p {
  color: hsl(215, 51%, 70%);
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
.details {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
.ethereum {
  color: cyan;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.clock {
  color: hsl(215, 51%, 70%);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
.ethereum img,
.clock img {
  padding-right: 0.3rem;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.2rem;
}
.creator {
  color: white;
}
.creator img {
  height: 1.7rem;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.text {
  position: relative;
  left: 0.7rem;
  bottom: 0.7rem;
}
.sub-text {
  color: white;
}
.sub-text:hover {
  color: cyan;
}
hr {
  border: 1px solid rgb(88, 88, 88);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Outfit"
    />
    <title>Frontend Mentor | NFT preview card component</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image-hover">
        <img src="./images/image-equilibrium.jpg" class="equilibrium" alt="" />
        <img src="./images/icon-view.svg" alt="view image" class="view" />
      </div>
      <h4>Equilibrium #3429</h4>
      <p>
        Our Equilibrium collection promotes <br />
        balance and calm.
      </p>
      <div class="details">
        <span class="ethereum"
          ><img src="./images/icon-ethereum.svg" alt="" />0.041 ETH</span
        >
        <span class="clock"
          ><img src="./images/icon-clock.svg" alt="" />3 days left</span
        >
      </div>
      <hr />
      <p class="creator">
        <img src="./images/image-avatar.png" alt="" /><span class="text"
          >Creation of<span class="sub-text"> Jules Wyvern</span></span
        >
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not much we can do without the **actual** image in the demo.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think any of the common image placeholder libraries have images with transparent backgrounds.